# VSTS CICD Build pipline failed after new .pfx file with latest expiration date added to repo

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have created a CICD pipline for a UWP project. The pipeline's powershell task with below mentioned code failed giving error message that ***Error APPX0108: The certificate specified has expired. For more information about renewing certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478***

So i created a new test certificate with an expirationdate of next year in Visual Studio 2017 and pushed the new certificate(.pfx) file to the repo. I also updated .csproj file to update it with name of new certificate.

Now i get the same error for a build solution task in the pipeline. I would like to know what i am missing. Do i have to add that certificate into my build server also?

**PowerShell script code:**

```
Param(
        [String]$pfxpath,
        [String]$password
    )


    if (-Not $pfxpath) {
        Write-Host "Certificate path not set"
        exit 1
    }

    if (-Not $password) {
        Write-Host "Password not set"
        exit 1
    }

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
    $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
    $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
    $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
    $store.Add($cert)
    $store.Close()
```

Comment: Can you share detail log? (Set system.debug variable to true) How do you specify $pfxpath parameter? Is it the new file path?

Comment: I got it resolved. It seems like the new certificate needs to be installed manually in to the build server..

Comment: @goldy14388, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, you could share your solution as an answer, and then mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I had to install certificate manually to the build server and I changed .csproj file with new certificate details and everything worked.

Comment: @goldy14388, Really thanks for your friendly reply, please see this link:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, so you could share your solution as an answer(not a comment) and accept it as the answer with green checkmark.